# Postgresql 12 logical replication catchup state (terminating walsender process due to replication timeout)

Tags: postgresql, replication, pg-logical

I have an issue with our logical replication which is still on catchup state.
It would read several lsn then got stuck on a particular lsn (EA/738D4DA8 both on sent_lsn and write_lsn) then reset again.
I read on the logs and found that it has a written log 'terminating walsender process due to replication timeout'
How can i resolve this issue?
I'm using Postgresql 12 under Windows Server 2019

Comment: Well, obvious: increase `wal_sender_timeout` on the primary.

Comment: Thanks @LaurenzAlbe 
I increased the sender time out (i also adjust the receiver timeout as well) and now the state changes to streaming

Answer (score 0):

If your WAL sender times out, the usual solution is to increase [`wal_sender_timeout`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-replication.html#GUC-WAL-SENDER-TIMEOUT) on the sending server.  You can set the parameter to 0 to disable the timeout mechanism at all.